# Issue with custom webpart multiple times on one page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am currently working on developing a webpart which runs some jquery with a toggling functionality on some of the elements in it. My issue here is that this webpart is meant to be used several times on the same webpartpage, which I have discovered courses me a lot of trouble, as the javascript will be loaded on the page several times trying to trigger functions on the same elements.

I thought it would be clever to create a couple methods to change different values here and there, but in the end I ended having the same issue.

So now I'm out of ideas and my skills with jquery and javascript are limited. So any help, samples, pointers - anything that make me come that much closer to a solution, I will be greatefull for.

The jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
      $('.togglingDiv').find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').click(function() {
             $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
      });
});
```

The HTML the jquery is toggling:

```
<dl class="togglingDiv">
    <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
    <dd>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
    <dd>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
    <dd>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
 </dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a similar scenario I used to replace  `<dl class="togglingDiv">` with `<dl id="togglingDiv" runat="server">`. When it has "runat server", Asp.net takes care of generating a different ID for each instance of your "togglingDiv".

Then you put the jQuery code in an ascx file and generate it using ASP.Net's `<%= .... %>` construct:

```
$(document).ready(function (){       
 $('#<%=togglingDiv.ClientId%>').find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').click(function()
  {             
  $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");   
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have your webparts load the javascript with the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stax6fw9.aspx). Something like this will only include the script once:

```
ClientScriptManager scriptManager = this.Page.ClientScript;

if (!scriptManager.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("scriptName"))
    scriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude("scriptName", "scriptUrl");
```

You can also use [.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) if you can't use an external file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your javascript in a file, you can use the [ScriptLink.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415843%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method.

ScriptLink encapsulates the ClientScriptManager calls along with additional functionality. Note that if the name parameter is a relative path, the javascript file needs to be in the 12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ *LCID* directory (where *LCID* is your language number).